# Can I use the Alignment(double x, double y) function on Column's children?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to have a column with 2 children widgets and wanted to align them by putting them in Align widgets and aligning them using 2 double coordinate values put into Align() function.

I was hoping I could freely align the 2 widgets on the plane of the column (that's covering the entire screen except for the app bar) using x and y coordinates of the function Align(). Changing the x value does impact the position of Align's child but changing the y value does nothing. Here's the code:

```
 Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: const Alignment(0, 0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () =>
                            Provider.of<FlipEvent>(context, listen: false)
                                .flipEvent(),
                        child: const Text('back', textScaleFactor: 3,)
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

if it matters the container get's returned by a Consumer, although I don't see a way that should impact the alignment of widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that a `Stack` widget would be suitable for positioning a widget in a unique location.

````
Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            color: Colors.white,
            // changed Column to Stack
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  // you can change these values to move the widget in relation to the top left of the screen
                  top: 500,
                  // bottom: 0,
                  // left: 0,
                  // right: 0,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => null,
                            // Provider.of<FlipEvent>(context, listen: false)
                            //     .flipEvent(),
                        child: const Text(
                          'back',
                          textScaleFactor: 3,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
    ```
````